# Chrome app "Bad client id: UNSUPPORTED"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I have a client Id set in my manifest file that matches the one I created in the google api console.

I created it as an application client ID.

Manifest.json:

```
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "mysecretclientID",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    ]
}
```

I'm testing this in the dev console for my chrome app with this code:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: false}, function(token){console.log(token);})
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed to select chrome application when setting up the client ID and I needed to add in my app id while testing locally which can be found in the chrome://extensions when developer mode is enabled.

[image]

Comment: what to enter for the application id? i'm starting out with chrome extension and there is no such store page url